# What should be the main concerns when generating extra data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-cleaning

I've been participating in a project where I had to cut most of the dataset due to mismeasurements/invalid values and we ended up with a small dataset.

*The dataset is regarding  the following:*

- Tool Deflection : **Metrology - Sensor Measured**
- Tool Wear : **Metrology - Sensor Measured**
- Piece - Form Accuracy : **Metrology - Sensor Measured**
- Piece - Roughness : **Metrology - Sensor Measured**
- Machine Input - Parameters : **System Inputs**

I thought of generating more data for each metrology dataset, using the Machine Inputs as reference, however, I feel like it could potentially bias my model.

As you can see, I'm quite confused with respect to this subject.

1. What should I expect if I move towards this solution?
2. Is there any restriction I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

It's as you said there is a chance of bias in the dataset. To avoid this you'll have to conform to an algorithm to generate data. Right off the bat, the solution I would propose is parametric methods. Find the statistical distribution of data and depending on that distribution fill in data accordingly.

If you want to know a bit more about parametric methods you can look at my answer here.

[What does it mean for the training data to be generated by a probability distribution over datasets](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26009/what-does-it-mean-for-the-training-data-to-be-generated-by-a-probability-distrib/26045#26045)

For some machine learning methods look at this answer I posted here.

[What are the best way to handle missing values](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23607/what-are-the-best-way-to-handle-missing-values/23609#23609)

There is never one single correct way to do what you're asking, but there are good ways and it depends on the nuances of your data.

Comment: Yes, Absolutely. 

I know there is not a single approach and that is why I asked before moving even further. There are so many methods and I could potentially miss some details.

Thanks for your help.